# How to rename a hash field efficiently in Redis

Tags: redis

I can `HGET mykey oldfield` and store `value` in my application and do `HSET newfield value`, how can I avoid copy my value just like `RENAMENX key newkey` while using hash?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to rename hashes in Redis. As @DidierSpezia said, the fastest/best way to do this is to use a Lua script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no specific command to do it, but you can use a server-side Lua script to execute the following operations atomically:

- hget key field
- hsetnx key newfield value
- if successful, hdel key field

You will pay for only one roundtrip, and you can handle errors (when the new field does already exist).

Comment: Thank you very much, It seems that I have to upgrade my Redis to 2.6, :P